# Chilli powder to tin tomatoes ratio for salsa

Tags: salsa, chill

I am just wanting to make my own medium hot salsa. But am wondering how much hot chilli powder to use per 14oz tin of tomatoes.

Comment: I’ve never used chili powder in salsa.  And all brands/blends are of a different level of heat, so you might just need to try some, taste it, add some more, etc.

Comment: And if you want it *hot* you might want to consider hot sauces like Tabasco Sauce and the like. You'll get an instant result and not see the chili powder grains in the salsa.

Comment: Even the matter of subjectivity aside, this question is impossible to answer because "chili powder" can mean very different things, their spicyness differs by orders of magnitude. Really, you'll have to try and taste and correct as needed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard recipe for salsa, so it's going to be entirely to your taste.  In fact, in Spanish "salsa" just means "sauce" so it can have just about an ingredient in it, in any quantity.